# CSS navigation menu won't rotate properly in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I've been given a design with a 90 degree rotated menu with dropdowns in it. Of course, I've got it working in every browser except IE8 (we aren't going to optimize for anything lower).

This is the staging site: http://williamsandports.com/wp/

The `#navbar` element itself rotates fine using

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
```

Using the awesome built-in IE "developer tools" I have found that the outermost `ul` which is `#menu-main-menu` is still un-rotated and hanging at the top of the screen so the dropdown elements aren't able to be interacted with properly.

Suggestions anyone? I'll take ANY fix, css, js, whatever to get this one finished up except static images of course :) You can view the same site in FF or Chrome to see what the finished solution should look like.

Comment: Working in the debug console of IE9 in IE8 mode I'm getting best results by restricting the width of `ul#menu-main-menu` and applying the rotate filter to its `<li>`s. Anti-aliasing sucks like a Hoover but it's a start ;)

Comment: This actually helped a great deal, thanks for taking a look. Can't wait til IE 8 is a thing of the past...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use transform in IE8. You can find out more: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform.
If you want rotate such as your site. You can use static images and css sprites for IE8. This is demo, I fix for IE 8 solution rotate.

## HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Solution rotate in IE8</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <!--[if gte IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="about">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="process">Our Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="client">Client List</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="consultation">Consultation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

#### - stylesheet.css: Use -webkit-transform: ratate(90deg)

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; }

.nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; }
  .nav-bar:before, .nav-bar:after {
    content: "";
    display: table; }
  .nav-bar:after {
    clear: both; }
  .nav-bar {
    *zoom: 1; }

.navigation {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; }
  .navigation li {
    display: inline-block; }
  .navigation a {
    color: #825a13;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
```

#### - ie.css: Fix when you use IE8 (use images and css sprites)

```
.navigation {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 40px; }
  .navigation li {
    display: block;
    float: left; }
  .navigation a {
    background: url(../img/nav.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 118px; }
    .navigation a.home {
      background-position: 0 0;
      height: 75px; }
    .navigation a.about {
      background-position: 0 -86px;
      height: 90px; }
    .navigation a.portfolio {
      background-position: 0 -187px;
      height: 101px; }
    .navigation a.process {
      background-position: 0 -299px; }
    .navigation a.client {
      background-position: 0 -435px; }
    .navigation a.consultation {
      background-position: 0 -571px; }
    .navigation a.contact {
      background-position: 0 -706px; }
```

### Images:

[image: Image Navigation]

I test working fine in IE8. Maybe this isn't best solution but I hope it can help you use in your site.